# How to merge two array of objects based on same key and remove others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays and I want to merge items that their id are same and remove the others. For example: Array 1:

```
 let arr1 = [
{ id: "123", name: "John" }, 
{ id: "345", name: "Sara" },
{ id: "542", name: "Jack" },
]
```

and Array 2 :

```
let arr2 = [
{ id: "123", phone: "021456" },
{ id: "345", phone: "0911256" }
]
```

and I need to merge these 2 arrays based on id and get this:

```
let arr3 =[
{ id: "123", phone: "021456", name: "John" },
{ id: "345", phone: "0911256", name: "Sara" }
]
```

How can I do this? I run the below code but unfortunately I have the third item but I do not want to have it

```
let arr3 = arr1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: And why don't you just do arr2.map instead of arr1.map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used map() and find() methods to merge two arrays based on the matching id property, creating a new array with the merged items while filtering out any unmatched items.

```
let arr3 = arr1.map(item1 => {
  const matchingItem = arr2.find(item2 => item2.id === item1.id);
  if (matchingItem) {
    return { ...item1, ...matchingItem };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(item => item !== null);
```

```js
let arr1 = [
{ id: "123", name: "John" }, 
{ id: "345", name: "Sara" },
{ id: "542", name: "Jack" },
];

let arr2 = [
{ id: "123", phone: "021456" },
{ id: "345", phone: "0911256" }
];


let arr3 = arr1.map(item1 => {
  const matchingItem = arr2.find(item2 => item2.id === item1.id);
  if (matchingItem) {
    return { ...item1, ...matchingItem };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(item => item !== null);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`, `find` and `spread operator (...)` to achieve this.

```js
let arr3 = arr2.reduce((acc, item) => {
    arr1.find((i) => {
        if (i.id === item.id) acc.push({...item, ...i});
    }) 
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: I think this works but also returning `true` or `false` from the find function would be more efficient.